# Prevent specific part of the text to be truncated

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, truncate

I have a long, single line text that is being truncated (`byTruncatingMiddle`). However, that string has a specific character in the middle, that I do not want to have cut off.

Let say the the text looks like this:

```
FooFooFooFooFooFoo - BarBarBarBarBarBarBar
```

Now I want to truncate the text without it removing the dash. So the result should look like this

```
FooFoo...-...arBarBar
```

Is that possible with default tools of `Swift` or is my only method to split the `UILabel` into 3 parts and truncate the tail and the head separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no default mode. I had the same problem and separated it to 3 UILabels as well. It is much easier than calculating the characters, actually you don't have to calculate anything, just setup the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

One way you could do this is have a max character count for the label and take the text up to that count and append with the "..." + Remaining string text like:

```
label.text = lblMessage.text.substring(0, maxChars) + "..." + lblMessage.text.substring(minChars, text.lenght)
```

basically logic is :

1. Find maximum characters that can be placed in label frame.
2. Now we have number character that are going to place in label. We are going to handle our own truncation logic here.
3. Calculate how much characters you can show in first half and second half
4. Concate those two string with "..."

Comment: This won't be very reliable as capital `M` takes way more space than lower case `i`